# Make Highcharts border color match background color on column chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Highcharts accepts an array of colors to use for series.  I'm making a column chart with transparent  fill color and I would like the border color to be the same color, but not transparent.  I know I can set the borderColor per series, but I'm not sure how many series I will have.  Is there a way to have the borderColor pick from an array, like the fill color does?

Here's what I have, and it works.  It just becomes difficult when I am adding series programatically. http://jsfiddle.net/scHST/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        colors: [
           'rgba(47,126,216,.3)', 
           'rgba(13,35,58,.3)', 
           'rgba(139,188,33,.3)', 
           'rgba(145,0,0,.3)', 
           'rgba(26,173,206,.3)', 
           'rgba(73,41,112,.3)',
           'rgba(242,143,67,.3)', 
           'rgba(119,161,229,.3)', 
           'rgba(196,37,37,.3)', 
           'rgba(166,201,106,.3)'
        ],
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                borderColor: '#303030',
                borderWidth: '2'
            }
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
            borderColor: 'rgba(47,126,216,1)'
        }, {
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
            borderColor: 'rgba(13,35,58,1)'
        }, {
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
            borderColor: 'rgba(139,188,33,1)'        
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: ah, maybe you could have a global colors array, and use some sort of function that returns a color based on series.length+1 when adding programatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe highcharts offers a way to set the background colors as an array unfortunately, but expanding on Rooster's suggestion, you could use a global array of colors and a function to access them, which might not be quite as convenient as you were hoping for, but it could at least bring an added benefit of handling the opacity conversion and letting you define the base colors once only, e.g.

```
var cols = new function() {
    var rgbs = [ 
        "47,126,216",
        "13,35,58",
        "139,188,33"
    ];
    this.get = function(i, a) {
        a = typeof a !== 'undefined' ? a : 1;
        return "rgba(" + rgbs[i] + "," + a + ")";
    };
    this.all = function(a) {
        var result = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < rgbs.length; i++) {
            result.push(this.get(i, a));   
        }
        return result;
    };
};
```

then use:

```
colors: cols.all(0.3)
```

and

```
borderColor: cols.get(0)
```

etc.

i.e. http://jsfiddle.net/M7Y8h/

Comment: Thanks, it's not the answer I wanted.  But, still very helpful.